# how to return result from AJAX javascript using POST [not using jquery]?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function AJAX(url,data)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
}

var a = AJAX('log.php','username=Leonard&password=asjdklaslkjdalskjdlaksjda');
```

When the function return it gives me "undefined".

Comment: Did the accepted answer solve your problem or did you just accept without testing?

Comment: @Christoph stop making snide comments - your comments on the two (identical) answers are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is asynchronous - it doesn't wait for the AJAX call to complete before returning so there's no results to return.

Try this:

```
function AJAX(url, data, callback, ctx)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
        {
            callback.call(ctx, xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
}
```

Note how you now have to supply a "callback function" that'll be invoked when the AJAX completes:

```
AJAX('log.php','username=Leonard&password=asjdklaslkjdalskjdlaksjda',
    function(result) {
        // do stuff with result
    }
);
```

**EDIT** the `ctx` parameter I added is optional - it's so that you can set what `this` will be when the callback is invoked.  This (no pun intended) will be useful if the callback is a method of an object rather than a standalone function.

Comment: @user1358505  it's optional, so that you can set what `this` should be in the callback - useful if the callback is a method of an object.

Comment: You don't need a callback, since the onreadystatechange with state=4 actually triggers, when the ajax-response returned...

Comment: @Christoph You're wrong - `onreadystatechange` is indeed a callback, but as written the code has no way to tell the original caller when that happened.  So the AJAX `onreadystatechange` callback has to call a user-supplied callback.

Comment: true, i overlooked the assignment in the last line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you `returns xmlhttp.responseText`, you're returning to the `onreadystatechange` property. Not very useful, is it?

Instead, use the asynchronous behavior to do the following:

```
function AJAX( url, data, callback ) {

    // Your stuff

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( xmlhttp.readyState === 4 ) {
            callback( xmlhttp.responseText )
        }
    }

    // Your other stuff

}
```

Then, you can use it like:

```
AJAX( url, data, function( responseText ) {
    // use responseText there
} )
```